# Where to Place Custom SPI JAR File in Latest Keycloak Docker Image?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi

I'm currently working on integrating a custom SPI (Service Provider Interface) into my Keycloak server, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to place my custom .jar file within the latest version of the Keycloak Docker image (v24.0.0).

I've thoroughly searched the documentation and various online resources, but most of the information seems to be outdated or specific to older versions of Keycloak. Additionally, the Docker images provided on Docker Hub for JBoss Keycloak are no longer maintained.
Could someone please provide guidance on where I should place my custom .jar file and the associated `META-INF/services/org.keycloak.provider.Spi` file within the latest version of the Keycloak Docker image?
I appreciate any help or pointers to relevant documentation that I may have missed.

Thank you!

Comment: it should be placed inside `: /opt/keycloak/lib/lib/deployment` folder.

Comment: Yes, that’s something I came across, however what surprise me is that when I see the Keycloak’s GitHub repo, I do not find any folder called opt. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: you have to go inside the `keycloak` running container there you'll find `opt`

Comment: Ok that’s fine thank you very much